# Why is assigning the Value property of cell causing code to end aburptly?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub FillRow(programCell As Range, storedProgramCell As Range)
    Dim counter As Integer

    For counter = 3 To 9
        Dim cellOffset As Integer
        cellOffset = counter - 3

        Dim currentStoredCell As Range
        Set currentStoredCell = storedProgramCell.Offset(0, cellOffset)

        Dim value As String
        value = currentStoredCell.value

        Dim currentTargetCell As Range
        Set currentTargetCell = programCell.Offset(0, cellOffset)

        MsgBox currentStoredCell.value 'Works correctly, prints correct value

        currentTargetCell.value = value
    Next counter
End Sub
```

The line:

```
currentTargetCell.value = value
```

causes the code to stop executing, with no error.

I added the expression to my watch list, then stepped through the routine. The expression was seen as a `Boolean`:

> [image]

This makes me think the expression is being viewed as a comparison, and the program abruptly ends since the returned `Boolean` is not being stored or used anywhere. I wouldn't doubt if I were wrong though.

I'm new to VBA, struggling to debug my program, so please forgive me if this is a petty mistake. I couldn't find any sources online that explains this problem.

Comment: add some error handling

Comment: Are you certain that programCell and storedProgramCell are both valid ranges, and that they're both the same size?

Comment: put `.Value` at the end of the first statement before the `=`

Comment: Is that sub inside a class module or a workbook/worksheet module? You may need to set VBA option Break On all Errors to ensure the debugger breaks in a class module. By default, VBA will not break in a class module, so that seems to be what you're seeing.

Comment: hmm, I see from your watch that the code is in module1. So it's not a class error, unless maybe the code that calls FillRow is in a class module?

Comment: @ScottCraner The results are the same. I took out the `.Value` in a hopeless attempt to fix it, I'll update my post

Comment: @ThunderFrame None of my routines are declared in class modules. They're all defined in the same module. The ranges have at least 1 cell, so wouldn't the loop get pass the first iteration and end on the second (if one of the ranges were to only have 1 cell)?

Comment: I think the ranges would need to be the same size, unless your Offset calls are returning ranges of the same size.

Comment: When you call `FillRow`, are you calling `FillRow(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"),Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2"))` or `FillRow(Range("A1"),Range("A2"))`? If the parent worksheet isn't specified, it's treated as an arbitrary range object not in the worksheets.

Comment: Make 2 lines for debug: `a = programCell.Offset(0, cellOffset).Value` and `storedProgramCell.Offset(0, cellOffset).Value = a`. Which line causes the error or unexpected execution stop? Debug values of `a`, `programCell` and `storedProgramCell` variables in _Locals_ window.

Comment: @omegastripes Execution stops `currentTargetCell.value = value` in my updated code. In locals, the values are as expected. I can even create a `MsgBox` containing the values. If I remove/comment out the assignment expression, it'll print every value in the specified row, so I'm not sure why the assignment is causing problems. I'll include my full code + the sheets I'm working with for reproduction.

Comment: @Yarnspinner The worksheets are correct, as it displays the correct values via `MsgBox` and the sheet specified via locals for both ranges are the correct sheets.

Comment: Add watch to the values, not the complete statement.

Comment: I don't know if it's upsetting Excel, but it confuses me to have a variable called `value` in this context.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?  Does the calling code have any error handler?

Comment: are there any event handlers ruling? have you also tried `MsgBox currentTargetCell.value` and `MsgBox value`?

Comment: Do you have any Change event code that might be responding to that? Or any conditional formatting that uses UDFs?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your subroutine with following code:

```
Private Sub FillRow(Dst As Range, Src As Range)

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim Srcx As Range
    Dim Dstx As Range

    Debug.Print "FillRow"
    Debug.Print Src.Address
    Debug.Print Dst.Address
    Debug.Print "Loop"
    For x = 0 To 6
        Debug.Print x
        Set Srcx = Src.Offset(0, x)
        Debug.Print Srcx.Address
        v = Srcx.Value
        Debug.Print TypeName(v)
        Set Dstx = Dst.Offset(0, x)
        Debug.Print Dstx.Address
        Dstx.Value = v
    Next
    Debug.Print "Completed"

End Sub
```

Run and post in your question Immediate window output.

Answer (score 0):

Value is a reserved word, even if vba does not raise an error on this name, you should not use it. Name it something else. Also, try setting it as a variant.

Comment: The initial problem appeared before `value` was suggested as variable name, and the question has been edited while unwinding.